# Kotlin Realm property is unsed

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I updated android studio and realm and spent alot of time going through errors to get it working. The below code worked fine before I updated everything.

Now it says Property `uid` is never used, and I get an error when trying to run the program. The app crashes when I run it and the error is:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void io.realm.ProxyState.setConstructionFinished()' on a null object reference
        at io.realm.com_myApp_SettingsRealmProxy.<init>(com_myApp_SettingsRealmProxy.java:82)
        at io.realm.DefaultRealmModuleMediator.newInstance(DefaultRealmModuleMediator.java:69)
        at io.realm.Realm.createObjectInternal(Realm.java:1001)
        at io.realm.Realm.createObject(Realm.java:977)

import io.realm.RealmObject
open class Settings() : RealmObject() {
    var name: String = ""
    var uid: Int = 0
    var settings = ""
}
```

I am using it as follows.

```
val statsRealm = realm.createObject(Settings::class.java)
   statsRealm.name = "MathTrainerStats"
   statsRealm.settings = generateJSONString()
   realm.commitTransaction()
```

This causes the error mentioned above. However if I add `uid` the error goes away.

```
val statsRealm = realm.createObject(Settings::class.java)
       statsRealm.uid = 22
       statsRealm.name = "MathTrainerStats"
       statsRealm.settings = generateJSONString()
       realm.commitTransaction()
```

I dont understand what the error is for since the code was working before I updated android studio gradle, kotlin etc....

Here is the apply plugin section

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'

apply plugin: 'realm-android'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
   .....
```

Comment: What exactly is the error when you run? There should be a warning that `uid` is not used... because you're not using it. Should not produce an error though. You'd get an error if `uid` was a primary key as it would default to zero, but this isn't the case according to the code. I assume you are calling `realm.beginTransaction()` prior to the `createObject...` code?

Comment: Yes I am calling realm.beginTransaction. When I run the app it crashes and gives the following error in logcat. java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void io.realm.ProxyState.setConstructionFinished()' on a null object reference I have added the error to original question to make it more readable.

Comment: Can you add: (a) a bit more of the stack trace from the exception (at least the next line, will give info on the realm object being created - possibly `Settings` but possibly not), and (b) add the 'apply plugin' section of your build.gradle with the realm and kotlin-kapt dependencies.

Comment: added the info you requested

Comment: Ok. Remembered this had been seen before - not as recent as I remember, can track on [this issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/issues/4579). Looks like only solutions were clean/rebuild, make sure Instant Run is turned off, and ensure realm-android was applied after kotlin-kapt. Try all that.

Comment: I just opened my project did not clean or anything and it is now working. What a terrible bug it seems hard to reproduce consistently. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Closing/reopening the project may have stopped Instant Run from being used - check it's disabled. Maybe they never actually fixed the problem, all I know is what is on the issue.